# I don't understand the motives behind the hold.

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold-questions

I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1107805/28555) which was placed on hold. The only person who has even a hint of interest in this type of question is https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1242/hans-lundmark, the others have no interest. Why aren't they giving the Riemann Hypothesis types a chance to interact? All of the data to support the question are present.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What is "triple dagger"? The close reason is valid.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, footnotes.

Comment: Does "Riemann" meam Riemann's hypothesis?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, Yes. But I couldn't find an appropriate tag for RH.

Comment: How do you know Hans Lundmark was interested in your question?  If you noticed, *he voted to close* the question you posted.

Comment: @anorton, He is the only one who had posts under the appropriate tags. So, I trust that his vote wasn't just being picky.

Comment: People have a general tendency to disregard posts related to proofs of the Riemann Hypothesis for obvious reasons.

Comment: I can assure you, Fred, that plenty of us are interested in the Riemann Hypothesis. It's just that we know something useless when we see it.

Answer (score 11):

Here are the reasons I voted to close:

- Unclear notation: what is the dagger? What is "Riemann"? Are the sum/product equations an assertion, or the conjecture?
- No context: where did these sums come from? Why do you expect them to be related to the Riemann hypothesis?